# Trying to compare a string value from database(firestore) to a inputted string from a text field. im using vue framework

Tags: javascript, string, google-cloud-firestore

```
<template>
  <div id="profile" class="collection with-header">
  <div class="profview">

  </div>
  <div class="search blue">
        <div class="input-field">
              <div class="input-field">
              <i class="material-icons prefix"></i>
              <input type="text" id="usernames" v-model="usernames" />
              <label class="white-text" for="email">Enter username</label>
            </div>
              <button
              v-on:click="followlist"
              class="btn btn-large btn-extended grey lighten-4 black-text"
            >
              Search
            </button>
            </div>
  </div>
    <div class="list right red">
      {{ word }}
      <li v-for="user in users" v-bind:key="user.id" class="collection-item">

      <button v-on:click="followlist">{{user.name}}</button>
      <!--<button v-on:click="seeoptions = !seeoptions">{{user.name}}</button>-->
      <div id="options" v-if="seeoptions">
      <li><button>Follow</button></li>
      <li><button>Block</button></li>  
      <li><button>View Profile</button></li>
      </div> 
    </li>
    </div>
   </div>
</template>

<style>
template{
background-color: blueviolet
}
</style>

<script>
//lets see if we can implement the search function using login as
// a template, change data to match with what u need
import db from './firebaseInit'
import firebase from "firebase";
var auth = firebase.auth();
var exists = false;

export default {

name: "followlist",
data: function () {
  return {
    users: [],
    loading: true,
    usernames: "",
    word: 'This is a friends list',
    content: 'Info of User',
    content2: 'A search bar',
    //seeoptions1: false,
   // seeoptions2: false,
    //seeoptions3: false
  }
},
methods:{
  followlist: function(e) {
    db.collection('users').get().then((querySnapshot) =>{
      this.loading = false
      //console.log("succes");
      //let inputtedname = document.getElementById("username").value;
      //let stringName = inputtedname.toString()
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
       // console.log("succes");
        
        // console.log(stringName);
        var tempname = this.usernames;
         var temp = doc.data().username;
       // console.log(this.username);
       //  console.log(temp);
         var curruser = this.username;
        if(tempname == temp){
                      console.log(doc.data().username)
        }
        else
          console.log("dont know")
        


      })
     // console.log(stringName)
    })
  },
 
},
created () {
 // Boolean userExists = false;
    
    db.collection('users').orderBy('dept').get().then((querySnapshot) => {
      this.loading = false
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        const data = {
          'id': doc.id,
          'name': doc.data().name,
          'dept': doc.data().dept,
          //'position': doc.data().position
        }
        this.users.push(data)
      })
    })
  }
}
</script>
```

ignore all the commented out console logs, anyways, i tried setting both to a variable, i tried doing it by straight comparing this.username to the one in database. its getting the username from the database correctly, ive console logged it and it worked fine, outputted all the usernames from database. however at the if statement, it will not compare them correctly if they are matches. also ignore the bottom created () section, its nnot doing anything currently. just was used to test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its probably due to a space in one of the string.

```
if(tempname.trim() == temp.trim()) {
  console.log(doc.data().username)
}
```

Comment: god dammit u genius. thank you. lol im fairly new to JS so had no idea there was a trim ability. thanks again!

Comment: I spent 3 days with this issue. I was literally snapping. My CTO came and fixed it in 10 seconds. I was on the brink of suicide. Can I get correct answer and upvote?

Comment: it doesnt let me upvote cause i barely created my profile, but i made it the answer, and i will come back to this and upvote once i do unlock it. thank you once again!